# Android App closes while creating a ListView Reference in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating a custom listview inside fragment. 
In my main activity there are two tabs. I have created two fragment classes "Subscribe" and "One Time". While the listView is reference in Subscribe Fragment, the app stops there. The code builds perfectly, but the apps stops there.

The XML for the fragment are similar except ListView ID.

fragment_subscibe.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".OneTime">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewSubscription">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in my Subscribe Fragment Java Class, I have following method.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewSubscription);
        Log.d("SOMETAG", "This doesn't print");
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), customername, phoneNo, amountleft);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position 1 Desc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(position == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position 2 Desc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(position == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position 3 Desc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(position == 3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position 4 Desc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subscribe, container, false);
    }
```

Commenting the part starting from Log Tag, creates the empty tabs.
I was populating the listView using this XML, row_order

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Customer Name"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_phoneno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Phone Number"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Amount Left"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Product Name">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_order"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Qty">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount_order"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Amount">

        </TextView>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/delivered_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

        </CheckBox>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I was following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Tm--PHhbJo

My Error Logs are below as requested:

```
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6692)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1140)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2709)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2825)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1557)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:110)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:203)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.407 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6339)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.408 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.408 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.408 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:945)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.542 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@91465fa[]
2020-04-13 23:32:04.558 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@91465fa[MainActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@1880975
2020-04-13 23:32:04.560 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Dumper init 2 threads <0x9ceecd60>
2020-04-13 23:32:04.560 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: <com.example.myapplication> is running.
2020-04-13 23:32:04.563 6602-6618/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x9e747d40
2020-04-13 23:32:04.581 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xa54b5400) (w:576 h:960 s:576 f:0x1 u:0x000100)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.582 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{f4bdd0a com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity,ident = 0}
2020-04-13 23:32:04.589 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{f4bdd0a com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@91465fa[MainActivity]
2020-04-13 23:32:04.616 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2020-04-13 23:32:04.619 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 6602
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.Subscribe.onCreateView(Subscribe.java:80)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:259)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6249)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20234)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2655)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1596)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1869)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1481)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7047)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:910)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:712)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:646)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:896)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
2020-04-13 23:32:04.619 6602-6602/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting. I updated the question and following the answer below got the error fixed. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call `getView` inside `createView` because you are creating the view (it is not yet created to get it) replace this line inside `createView`:

```
listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewSubscription);
```

with these lines:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subscribe, container, false);
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewSubscription);
// other codes...
return rootView// return from `createView`
```